# rostest code coverage

Tags: python, rostest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm writing tests in python, and I'm hoping to use rostest and get a coverage report of my code.

I notice on the [unittest page](http://wiki.ros.org/unittest#unittest_code) it says that this can be done by adding a `coverage_packages` argument to `rostest.rosrun`. Doing so gives me the following error in my test output:

`TypeError: rosrun() got an unexpected keyword argument 'coverage_packages'`

If I omit this argument and the tests actually run, no coverage report is generated anywhere I can see (neither log directory nor project directory).

I see that rosunit even has [helper scripts](http://wiki.ros.org/rosunit#Helper_Scripts) for generating these... is this all deprecated and unsupported? Or is there a way to get code coverage reports?

Basic info:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- ROS Groovy
- rosbuild
- python

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/181892/rostest-code-coverage/) by [mbforbes](https://answers.ros.org/users/15401/mbforbes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2014-07-01

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/690d68d33bc747e8e00be16610f78b9eac62c5fd/tools/rostest/src/rostest/__init__.py#L104), it seems that `rostest.rosrun` does not take 5th argument `coverage_package`.

```
def rosrun(package, test_name, test, sysargs=None):
```

Instead, `unitrun` (seems deprecated) takes it ([code](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/690d68d33bc747e8e00be16610f78b9eac62c5fd/tools/rostest/src/rostest/__init__.py#L169)).

```
def unitrun(package, test_name, test, sysargs=None, coverage_packages=None):
    :
    @param coverage_packages: list of Python package to compute coverage results for. Defaults to package
    @type coverage_packages: [str]
```

It would be beneficial to the community if you could test this method and provide how it goes.

Btw, with `coverage_packages` I think you need to give actual name of the packages; what your error message indicates is you gave `coverage_packages` string.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mbforbes](https://answers.ros.org/users/15401/mbforbes/) on 2014-07-03**:
Thanks Isaac for looking into this!

After seeing `unitrun` is deprecated, I decided to just add code coverage myself, because it's quite easy. Here's an example for anyone wondering:
http://git.io/__B2wg

(Also thanks for editing my question---my reputation wasn't high enough to post links :-)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking the [rosrun](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/690d68d33bc747e8e00be16610f78b9eac62c5fd/tools/rostest/src/rostest/__init__.py#L104) code it seems that it actually does support coverage through the `sysargs` parameter:  `sysargs=--cov`

---

Originally posted by [Victor Gonzalez-Pacheco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2660/victor-gonzalez-pacheco/) with karma: 396 on 2015-01-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-01-13**:
Looks like you're right. This needs to be documented.

**Comment by [Victor Gonzalez-Pacheco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2660/victor-gonzalez-pacheco/) on 2015-01-17**:
Indeed, it would be great to have it documented. Actually, after posting the question I've tried to get some coverage of my code without success. Do you know where we can open the issue? I'm not sure wether to report this to the wiki or to rosrun's repo.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-01-17**:
Opening an issue on [ros_comm](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues) where `rostest` resides is a good start I think.

**Comment by [Victor Gonzalez-Pacheco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2660/victor-gonzalez-pacheco/) on 2015-01-20**:
Opened!
See `ros_comm` [#553](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/553)